# Resize Window to child content control

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I have a ContentControl that swaps out views based on a 'CurrentPage' property chosen in the ViewModel.

I'm using a Window to host this ContentControl - it contains UserControl views and acts a persistent View/ViewModel for the application.

How do I bind the size of the Window to the size of the *currently* displayed content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to data bind the size of the `Window` to its content. There is a property called [`Window.SizeToContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx) that will have the same effect. From the linked page on MSDN:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a window will automatically size itself to fit the size of its content.

A typical example of its use would be this:

```
// Automatically resize height and width relative to content 
this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
```